# Structs and char strings

Tags: c, string, struct, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 3 // students in class 
#define LEN 20 // max lengths stydent's name

typedef struct {
    char name[LEN];
    int am;
    float tv;
}student;

void read (student board[]) {       //this function should fill the board of structs
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
        printf("\n give student's name");
        scanf ("%s",&board[i].name);
    }

}

void read (student board[]);

int main (void) {
    student class[MAX];
    read (class);
return 0;   
}
```

when i try to compile it i get this error

> let2.c:15:3: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wformat=]
>   let2.c:15:3: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wformat=]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lose the `&` in your `scanf` call.  You want a pointer to the first character of the string, not a pointer to the array itself:

```
scanf("%s", board[i].name);
```

Or, equivalently:

```
scanf("%s", &board[i].name[0]);
```

Comment: WOw !! So fast and accurate. Thank you very much !! 

not a pointer to the array itself.

could you explain that a litle bit more?

Comment: This would be a great opportunity to mention the dangers of `%s` without a maximum field width.

Comment: I have to say that this is kind of puzzling, since for any `Type arr[N]`, the values of `arr` and `&arr` are equal as long as you "test them" in the scope of declaration of `arr`. So either the compiler issues a futile warning here, or the values of `board[i].name` and `&board[i].name` are not identical since they are not used in the "original" scope of declaration.